# Using a Set Range to Sort, but it never changes the value after using it once

Tags: excel, vba, sorting, set

I have a code here that works for its base goal...
Double clicking on a header will sort by Column D, then Sort by the Column Double Clicked.

Yes, I know that this can be more easily accomplished through a Multiple Sort, but thats not an option for...reasons.

The problem, is that after the code has been run once, where it works just fine, it "seems" to be permenantly setting my "Set KeyRange" to the clicked value.

If I manually resort the table, and try to Doubleclick a new header, it still sorts it according to the header selected the first time.

How can I fix this?  Thanks.  I tried adding a new Set Key range command near the end, but that did nothing, or broke it.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
Dim KeyRange As Range
Dim ColumnCount As Integer
ColumnCount = Range("A1:D12").Columns.Count
Cancel = False
If Target.Row = 1 And Target.Column <= ColumnCount Then
Cancel = True
Set KeyRange = Range(Target.Address)
End If
With ActiveSheet.Sort
     .SortFields.Add Key:=Range("D1"), Order:=xlAscending
     .SortFields.Add Key:=KeyRange, Order:=xlAscending
     .SetRange Range("A1:D12")
     .Header = xlYes
     .Apply
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks!   I think the Sort clear was the biggest thing that was missing on my end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code worked almost perfect for me. The only thing I did was excluding from `If ...Then...End If` if `Target`was not in row 1 or more than 4 column.

Also I added `.SortFields.Clear`, you need to clear the previous order.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)

Dim KeyRange As Range
Dim ColumnCount As Integer
ColumnCount = Range("A1:D12").Columns.Count
Cancel = False
If Target.Row = 1 And Target.Column <= ColumnCount Then
    Cancel = True
    Set KeyRange = Range(Target.Address)
    With ActiveSheet.Sort
         .SortFields.Clear
         .SortFields.Add Key:=Range("D1"), Order:=xlAscending
         .SortFields.Add Key:=KeyRange, Order:=xlAscending
         .SetRange Range("A1:D12")
         .Header = xlYes
         .Apply
    End With
End If
End Sub
```

This code works perfect for me. I click on any header, and it sorts my data by column D and then the header clicked.

Also, notice that **if your values in column D (your first criteria) are all unique and the rows are already ordered, you won't notice any visible change** because ordering by column D is your first criteria.